# How do I create multiple buttons that play different sounds while still having them styled?

Tags: javascript

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to code this. I have absolutely no experience with JavaScript so I followed a tutorial. I'm trying to create a page full of buttons, but each button plays a different audio. Right now I have made two buttons, but both of them play the same exact sound. I tried looking at some other posts on stack, but I'm having trouble fixing it without removing the styling that I've already applied to it.

````
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        a button
    </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;

        }
        body{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            background: black;
            display: flex;
            jusitfy-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        #button{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            border-width: 4px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            font-size: 40px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: black;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        #button2{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            border-width: 4px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            font-size: 40px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: black;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<button id="button" onclick="audio.play();"> click me </button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = "audio/yay.mp3"; 
</script>
<button id="button2" onclick="audio.play();"> click me </button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = "audio/waitwhat.mp3"; 
</script>
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of audios, each having a different src, and call the function for the audio at the corresponding index.
Also, you don't need two "script" tags, you can write the entire logic into a single one.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      // creates an array of audios and assigns the src to each of them
      const srcArr = ['audio/waitwhat.mp3', 'audio/yay.mp3'];
      const audios = new Array(srcArr.length).fill(new Audio());
      audios.forEach((audio, index) => audio.src = srcArr[index]);
</script>
```

And then pass the corresponding audio to the onclick function based on the index of the src in the srcArr

```html
<button id="button" onclick="audios[0].play();"> click me </button>
<button id="button" onclick="audios[1].play();"> click me </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have with the same sounds playing is because your both `audio` have the same name, and so when you call `audio.play` the javascript interpreter can not differentiate which sound exactly you want to play.

Basically to fix the issue you just need to give your two audio files different names, like `audio1`, and `audio2`.

Example:

```html
<button id="button" onclick="audio1.play();"> click me (audio-1)</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const audio1 = { play() { console.log('play audio-1') } };
</script>

<button id="button2" onclick="audio2.play();"> click me (audio-2)</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const audio2 = { play() { console.log('play audio-2') } };
</script>
```